# azure group deployment - resourceGroupName is outside the valid range

Tags: azure

I just wanted to create a new vm via

```
azure group deployment create –g snowgroup -n snow-route-2 -f vm.json
```

Is asks for the networkid

```
/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/snowgroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/snowroute-nic
```

and i get the following error.

```
 resourceGroupName is outside the valid range.
```

I tried another name before and got the same error.

So what would be a valid name?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the resource group name as the last parameter. The error "outside the valid range" means you specified a group name of zero length (i.e. it's missing). Even though you specified it explicitly with -g, I think it needs to be specified again as the last parameter. Check `azure group deployment create -h` for usage.